# AWS Athena create table and partition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-athena

I stored my sensor data in S3 (write data every 5 minutes):

```
farm_iot/sensor_data/farm/farm0001/sensor01/1541252701443
```

1541252701443 is a json file containing measurements:

```
{  "temperature": 14.78,  "pressure": 961.70,  "humidity": 68.32}
```

I am definitely missing some hive skill. Unfortunately I did not find an example that extracts timeseries json data that gets me started. I am also not sure wheather Hive / Athena does support this kind of data wresting.

I am struggeling with creating an Athena table for this data...

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS farm.sensor_data (
  device string,
  sensor string,
  data_point string,
  value double
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://farm-iot/sensor_data/farm/farm0001/sensor01/'
PARTITIONED BY (timestamp string)
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

Another road I am thinking is to store the data in a structure that is easier to process / maybe I have not partitioned the data enough??!

so maybe I should add **dt** to the structure like this:

```
farm_iot/sensor_data/2018-11-03-02-45-02/farm/farm0001/sensor01/1541252701443
```

still does not get me where I want to be:

```
+---------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------+
| timestamp     | device   | sensor   | data_point  | value  |
+---------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------+
| 1541252701443 | farm0001 | sensor01 | temperature |  14.78 |
+---------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------+
| 1541252701443 | farm0001 | sensor01 | humidity    |  68.32 |
+---------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------+
| 1541252701443 | farm0001 | sensor01 | pressure    | 961.70 |
+---------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------+
```

Any pointer towards this goal would be much appreciated. Thank you!

please note: I do not want to use glue and like to understand how to do it manually. besides glue already created ~16.000 tables yesterday :)

Comment: do you face an error writing the data or when creating the table? please post the error message.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala sorry this is not an "I have an error question"

Comment: just edited with an alternative to keep the data in its current format, however performance will not be as good as using partitions

Comment: just added a post with the details on what I am doing with that https://www.mark-fink.de/2018-12-09-query-aws-athena-from-jupyter-notebook/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all many thanks to @hlagos for his help.

AWS Athena was not able to transform the json sensor data the way I needed it (we discussed this in comments to @hlagos answer). Consequently the "simplest" way to deal with that situation was to change the data format from json to CSV to be closer to the format I needed.

I now store the sensor data in S3 in CSV format (write data every 5 minutes) plus I added the day and device partitions we discussed.

Resulting folder structure:

```
farm_iot/sensor_data/farm/day=20181129/device=farm0001/1543535738493
```

the data contents of the CSV file:

```
sensor01,temperature,2.82
sensor01,pressure,952.83
sensor01,humidity,83.64
sensor02,temperature,2.61
sensor02,pressure,952.74
sensor02,humidity,82.41
```

the AWS Athena table definition:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS farm.sensor_data (
  `sensor` string,
  `data_point` string,
  `value` double 
) 
PARTITIONED BY (day string, device string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ESCAPED BY '\\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 's3://farm-iot/sensor_data/farm/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

The partitions I add like this (later I will have a script to create the partitions in advance):

```
msck repair table farm.sensor_data
```

now I can query the data:

```
select regexp_extract("$path", '[^/]+$') as timestamp, device, sensor, 
    data_point, value from farm.sensor_data where day='20181104'

Results
    timestamp       device      sensor      data_point  value
1   1541310040278   farm0001    sensor01    temperature 21.61
2   1541310040278   farm0001    sensor01    pressure    643.65
3   1541310040278   farm0001    sensor01    humidity    74.84
4   1541310040278   farm0001    sensor02    temperature 9.14
5   1541310040278   farm0001    sensor02    pressure    956.04
6   1541310040278   farm0001    sensor02    humidity    88.01
7   1541311840309   farm0001    sensor01    temperature 21.61
8   ...
```

Answer (score 10):

Let me try to explain a few problems that I see on front.

- It looks like your desired output expect some data which is part of the path file location, device and sensor, however it is not defined as part of your table definition, only columns in the table definition or [virtual columns](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns) will be available.
- Several small files could impact the performance of your queries (but this will not affect your desired result)
- Hive partitions are used to improve queries' performance avoiding scan the 
  all the data. Partitions point to folders, in this case you are trying to access to specific files
- Your desired output is basically exploding 1 record in several records, this shouldn't be handled at table definition, can be done through your select statement
- Hive partitions have the naming convention of `partitionname=partitionvalue`, this is not mandatory but useful if you want  to take advance of commands to automatically add partitions based on your folder structures.

This is how I would solve your problem if you will mainly query by sensor or device

### Change structure of your data

Your folder sturcture ideally should go from

```
farm_iot/sensor_data/farm/farm0001/sensor01/1541252701443
```

to    farm_iot/sensor_data/farm/device=farm0001/sensor=sensor01/1541252701443

### Change your table definition

Your table definition should contain your partition locations to be able to select it without regex and take advantage of the performance improvement of it (I am guessing a common query will filter by device or sensor. Additional to that you need to add all your json columns that are part of your file

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS farm.sensor_data (
  temperature double,
  preassure double,
  humidity double
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://farm-iot/sensor_data/farm/'
PARTITIONED BY (device string, sensor string)
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

### Querying your data

We are missing the timestamp which is essentially part of your filename with the json input. We can include the file name during the select statement using virtual column `INPUT__FILE__NAME` as follow

```
select device, sensor, temperature, preassure, humidity, INPUT__FILE__NAME as mytimestamp from farm.sensor_data
```

If you want preassure, temperature and humidity and different rows, I would recommend create an array with those three and explode it, it should be much efficient that run 3 queries using UNION ALL to append the results

### Adding new partition

If you follow Hive convention, you can take advantage of the command [msck repair table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)) to automatically add new partitions once new devices/sensors are included. In the worst case if you want to keep your folder structure, you can add partitions as follow

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (device='farm0001', sensor='sensor01') location 's3://farm_iot/sensor_data/farm/farm0001/sensor01'
```

NOTE: new partitions will not be automatically added, you always need to add them

I tried to add as much detail as possible. If something is not clear let me know.

EDIT:
If your queries will be mostly based on timeseries (date range for example) I would recommend add a partition at day level (not smaller than this) to improve the performance of your queries. So your table definition would looks like

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS farm.sensor_data (
  temperature double,
  preassure double,
  humidity double
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://farm-iot/sensor_data/farm/'
PARTITIONED BY (dt=long, device string, sensor string)
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

And your folder structure would looks like

farm_iot/sensor_data/farm/dt=20191204/device=farm0001/sensor=sensor01/1541252701443

As clarification, you do not need to modify the table for each new partition, only add this partitions to the table, this is essentially how Hive will know that a new partition was created. If you decide to use partitions, this is the only way, if you don't (this will impact the performance), there are some other alternatives to make it work

EDIT2:

If you want to keep your data  structure as is and do not use partitions, it is possible to get the expected results as follow

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yourdb.sensordata (
  temperature double,
  pressure double,
  humidity double
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) 
LOCATION 's3://farm-iot/sensor_data/farm/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');

SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=TRUE;
SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=TRUE;
select * from yourdb.sensordata;

select 
split(input__file__name, "/")[size(split(input__file__name, "/")) - 1] as ts,
split(input__file__name, "/")[size(split(input__file__name, "/")) - 3] as device,
split(input__file__name, "/")[size(split(input__file__name, "/")) - 2] as sensor,
'temperature' as data_point,
temperature as value
from yourdb.sensordata
union all
select 
split(input__file__name, "/")[size(split(input__file__name, "/")) - 1] as ts,
split(input__file__name, "/")[size(split(input__file__name, "/")) - 3] as device,
split(input__file__name, "/")[size(split(input__file__name, "/")) - 2] as sensor,
'pressure' as data_point,
pressure as value
from yourdb.sensordata
union all
select 
split(input__file__name, "/")[size(split(input__file__name, "/")) - 1] as ts,
split(input__file__name, "/")[size(split(input__file__name, "/")) - 3] as device,
split(input__file__name, "/")[size(split(input__file__name, "/")) - 2] as sensor,
'humidity' as data_point,
humidity as value
from yourdb.sensordata;
```

As you see, I am getting the most of the information from the file path, however it is required to set some flags to tell Hive read folders recursively

```
ts,device,sensor,_data_point,value
1541252701443,farm0001,sensor01,temperature,14.78
1541252701443,farm0001,sensor01,pressure,961.7
1541252701443,farm0001,sensor01,humidity,68.32
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am not very fond of your suggested table change because I would have to change the table definition with every new sensor type I introduce. If I understand you correctly then it is not possible to hive the json data into the format I want. This would mean I'd better store the sensor data in csv format ('device', 'sensor', 'data_point', 'value' ). The device partition might turn out useful. I did not mention this before but the common query will filter the timeseries by time-slice like a day or week from two years of data.

Comment: if I use the dt and device partitions like "farm_iot/sensor_data/dt=2018-11-03-02-45-02/farm/device=farm0001/sensor01/1541252701443" how does the "correllation" between dt and mytimestamp in the query work? This probably is some hive magic I do not unserstand (yet). Btw. does using partitions mean I have to recreate the table before every query so I can get recent data? Somehow reminds me of CouchDB a few years back...

Comment: It is not required to recreate the table, you just need to run the msck repair table command to add any new partitions, in this case only if you add new folders at device or sensor level herarchy, no table recreation required.  you should be able to load the json that you are getting without problem, csv or json will not make any difference from this point of view. About your suggestion of adding dt to the partition, it makes sense for me, if this will be a common query, however I would recommend add that at folder level only at day level, you will ended up

Comment: with too many partitions which will also impact the performance. Let me update my answer about this point

Comment: if I read your code correctly you put a lot of magic into the query. My plan was to put all that stuff into the table definition so the query can be simple (and hopefully performant). Not convinced whether this goes into the right direction.

Comment: did you note my comments above?

Comment: yes, if that is the case, I would defenitly go for the partition option, if you want something simpler but maybe not that performer, you can go for the last option and mount a view on top of it. The view will abstract all the "magic" being done by the query

Comment: just so we are clear. I very much apprechiate your input - it tremendously helped me to think this through. Your points are good and your answers correct. However this is not a text book question and I can't help thinking that we have not seen the simplest / optimal solution to the problem. Over the weekend I try to work out the details to what I outlined as solution approach in my first comment above. If nobody comes up with an even better solution I am happy to reward you the bounty.

Comment: no problem at all, glad to help. I tried to do not touch or change how you store the data (you do not always have the control for it). I am glad it was helpful to get  into a simpler solution